# Beginner Animator: Unable to unify FK & IK in animation (footage of issue linked)

Tags: animation, rigify

I had initially thought that rigifying the metarig to the body would unite the body with the rig, but I am missing some fundamentals here I assume.

Moving my IK is independent to the FK, as shown here: https://clips.twitch.tv/CreativeSpineySrirachaPoooound-utS8Ml-oge6JPvMF

[image: screenshot external video]

What am I misunderstanding? Why can't the arm just pose with the rig? I also thought the dotted line meant a parent-child relationship... Not sure anymore...

Comment: It appears you have the two rigs separated on two different layers? If that's the case, then I believe the only way to make the fk snap with ik is by scripting it (this is what I've read from other forums; I haven't actually tried it myself)
edit: also note, you'll need to create switch between fk and ik using drivers first (if you haven't done so already)

Answer (score 0):

Rigify's generated rig comes with FK and IK control bones. The meta rig is just used to align everything in its place. The FK (green) and IK controls (red) work independently from each other. Default is IK.

In the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel there are buttons in the *Rig Main Properties* section. There, you can switch between IK and FK with the *IK-FK ("bone name")* slider (0=IK, 1=FK). Or use the snap buttons *IK->FK ("bone name")* and *FK->IK ("bone name")* to copy the pose and sync them.

[image: Rigify properties]

(*hand.L* is the bone name of the left hand in this example)

Tutorial video: [[Blender 2.8/2.9] Rigify Tutorial #08 - Posing the Rigify rig](https://youtu.be/vKgH5zXIYmM)